# How to truncate some elements from the end of the array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I don't predict how many elements could be there in the array. And I want to keep only first five elements of the array and truncate the rest of the elements. Is there any build in PHP function to perform this action?

Comment: all functions are listed in manual, http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
$truncated_array = array_slice ( $full_array , 0, 5 )
```